# netplan command to re-arrange nameserver ips in resolv.conf

Tags: 18.04

I have 2 network interfaces on the `Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS`. Interface `ens160` is public network, which take internet traffic and Interface `ens192` is internal network. Each interface has it sets of DNS servers. When I run `netplan apply` command I get internal network DNS Servers as top 2 name servers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file instead of public network's DNS servers This is causing slowness when talking to internet.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.120.0.10 <---internal network DNS Server
nameserver 10.120.0.20 <---internal network DNS Server
nameserver 190.90.7.20 <---public network DNS Server
# Too many DNS servers configured, the following entries may be ignored.
nameserver 190.90.7.50 <---public network DNS Server
search domain.com
#
```

Comment: Try separating your ethernet interfaces into two different .yaml files, and start their filenames with 01- and 02-, using the lowered numbered file with public DNS servers, and the higher numbered file with internal DNS servers. (reverse this if they are still in the wrong order in /etc/resolv.conf).

Comment: It didn't work. I created two separate files for each interface under `/etc/netplan` directory.

Comment: When using two files, edit your question with the output of `resolvectl`. I'm curious where it places the DNS servers in relation to the interfaces.